# Elasticsearch Bulk data insertion - JsonParseException[Unexpected character - Using PHP

Tags: php, json, curl, elasticsearch, bulk

While indexing the bulk data using PHP curl method I am getting the exception as `"error":"JsonParseException[Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@14abb68; line: 1, column: 18]]","status":500}`

Kindly find below code which I am using for the same and do let me know what could be wrong over here.

```
<?php
 $ch = curl_init();
$method = "POST";
$url = "http://192.168.1.204/myindex/test/_bulk";


$qry = '
{"index":{"_index": "myindex","_type":"test"}}
{
    "product_id": 1,
    "title": "mobile"
}
{"index":{"_index": "myindex","_type":"test"}}
{
    "product_id": 2,
    "title": "laptop",
}
';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 9200);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, strtoupper($method));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $qry);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
  echo $result;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the correct format (and there is an additional comma at the second element).
It should be:

```
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
....
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
```

Extracted from the documentation of [elasticsearch - bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

So, you should add the data using the following format:

```
{"index":{"_index": "myindex","_type":"test"}}
{"product_id": 1,"title": "mobile"}
{"index":{"_index": "myindex","_type":"test"}}
{"product_id": 2,"title": "laptop"}
```